# String escape without database connection

Tags: c++, libpqxx

I am trying to use the string escaping functionality without having access to an open pqxx::connection.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <pqxx/pqxx>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    pqxx::connection c;
    std::cout << c.quote("this is a test") << std::endl;
}
```

It throws that my connection was broken. Can someone give me a sign, if there's another way to achieve this (hopefully without database connection)? Have I overlooked something?

#### Update:

I found a possible reasoning for why the active connection might be required for this functionality in the [docs of libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING):

> The only difference from PQescapeStringConn is that PQescapeString does not take PGconn or error parameters. Because of this, it cannot adjust its behavior depending on the connection properties (such as character encoding) and therefore it might give the wrong results. Also, it has no way to report error conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The way I solved the problem, it is showed below.
It is a trick that not fully solve the problem, but, the lazy part it is only executed once in entirely runtime excecution, and it is minimized to the maximum.
The real problem is the way libpqxx was written.

```
std::string
quote(const std::string& str, const std::string& database_connection)
{
    try {
        static pqxx::lazyconnection C {database_connection};
        static bool disconnect = true;
        if(disconnect) {
            C.disconnect();
            disconnect = false;
        }
        return C.quote(str);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) { throw e.what(); }
}
```

Comment: This is bad, escape is a util function, should be sperate.

Comment: FWIW I found a possible reasoning why the connection might be required for this functionality in the [docs of libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-ESCAPE-STRING): _"Because of this, it cannot adjust its behavior depending on the connection properties (such as character encoding) and therefore it might give the wrong results."_

Answer (score 0):

character escape sequences can easily be used without using pqxx at all.

```
std::cout << "\"This is a qoute\"" << std::endl;
```

The '\' character starts an escape sequence. for qoutes you just say \"

other sequences:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: This is about correctly escaping a string to be used in an SQL-statement. Not about escaping characters in a C-string. It can't be easily done for arbitrary input strings. See also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Incorrectly_filtered_escape_characters).